# How to get coverage report with Typescript + Babel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, jestjs

I am creating a `Typescript` + `Babel` + `React` application and trying to set test environment. By now I use `Jest`, but it is not seem to produce correct coverage report for `Typescript` + `Babel` chain. Is there a way to get correct coverage report for `Typescript` + `Babel` with `Jest`? Or I should use `Mocha`, `nyc`, etc.?

Comment: I'd say using `istanbul` might be what you are looking for. Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027197/how-do-you-use-istanbul-code-coverage-with-transpiled-typescript and https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/09/29/code-coverage-for-typescript-and-other-transpiled-languages/